# Edit and update my SQL Server database with the edit and update

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a SQL Server table with 5 columns. `col1` is the primary key. I an working in ASP.net 4.0.

I want to be able to edit and update my SQL Server table with the edit and update respectively.

I am having a little trouble with the update.  Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"  OnRowEditing="Gridview1_OnRowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_OnRowUpdating">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
Sub ShowGrid()
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    connStr = "connection string works"
    cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM table1;"
    Dim MyDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim MyDataTable As New DataTable()
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Using MyDataAdaptor As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    MyDataAdaptor.Fill(MyDataSet)
                    MyDataTable = MyDataSet.Tables(0)
                    GridView1.EditIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState("edit"))
                    GridView1.DataSource = MyDataTable
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    ViewState("edit") = GridView1.EditIndex
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    connStr = "connection string works"
    cmdStr = "UPDATE table1 SET (col2=@col2,col3=@col3,col4=@col4,col5=@col5) WHERE col1=@col1;"
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col3", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col4", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col5", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Text)

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    ViewState("edit") = e.RowIndex
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do the whole thing in `.aspx` page. I wouldn't use code behind if there is specific need for it to customize things.

Comment: It is possible to do it in .aspx.vb right?

Comment: I use ShowGrid for all of my Gridview applications and you can not do that in a .aspx page.

Comment: You can set it's visible property from code behind, if that is all what you are trying to do. Show or not show.